# Remove Duplicates and SUM

Tags: sql

```
    SELECT 

         sku_master.sku
       , sku_master.description
       , sku_master.min_on_hand
       , sku_master.max_on_hand
       , location_inventory.qty_on_hand

  FROM [FCI].[dbo].[location_inventory]
  JOIN [FCI].dbo.[sku_master] ON location_inventory.sku = sku_master.sku
  WHERE min_on_hand > 0
  GROUP BY sku_master.sku
```

What I am trying to achieve by this is I want to group all the duplicates SKU's together and sum the qty_on_hand.  I just can't figure out how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you the total by SKU:

```
SELECT 
     sku_master.sku
   , sum(location_inventory.qty_on_hand) as total_qty_on_hand
FROM [FCI].[dbo].[location_inventory]
JOIN [FCI].dbo.[sku_master] ON location_inventory.sku = sku_master.sku
WHERE min_on_hand > 0
GROUP BY sku_master.sku
```

If you want other attributes frm the SKU_MASTER table as well, you can join this result to another query:

```
SELECT 
     sku_master.sku
   , sku_master.description
   , sku_master.min_on_hand
   , sku_master.max_on_hand
   , x.total_qty_on_hand
FROM [FCI].dbo.[sku_master]
inner join
(
  SELECT 
     sku_master.sku
   , sum(location_inventory.qty_on_hand) as total_qty_on_hand
  FROM [FCI].[dbo].[location_inventory]
  JOIN [FCI].dbo.[sku_master] ON location_inventory.sku = sku_master.sku
  WHERE min_on_hand > 0
  GROUP BY sku_master.sku
) x on sku_master.sku = x.sku
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT 
         sku_master.sku
       , sku_master.description
       , sku_master.min_on_hand
       , sku_master.max_on_hand
       , sum(location_inventory.qty_on_hand)
  FROM [FCI].[dbo].[location_inventory]
  JOIN [FCI].dbo.[sku_master] ON location_inventory.sku = sku_master.sku
  WHERE min_on_hand > 0
  GROUP BY sku_master.sku, 
           sku_master.description, 
           sku_master.min_on_hand,
           sku_master.max_on_hand;
```

Comment: This will work only if no duplicate `sku` with different `description` or `min_on_hand` in the `sku_master` table

Comment: @Fabio Yes, but I suppose all the columns other then sku depends on sku. So for the same skus all other columns have equal values

Comment: If I could put a check for two answers I would because this one works for that is intended as well, and based on the other comments to this answer I have learned even more and I thank you's!

Comment: @eternityhq I don't need a check. I'm glad that my quess was correct. The answer you've chosen is more universal and the author put more effort on it. However, if sku is primary key I'd recommend just grouping as it's less resource demanding.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sku_master.sku
, SUM(location_inventory.qty_on_hand)
FROM [FCI].[dbo].[location_inventory]
JOIN [FCI].dbo.[sku_master] ON location_inventory.sku = sku_master.sku
WHERE sku_master.min_on_hand > 0
GROUP BY sku_master.sku
```